# radio buttons not allowing me to toggle in react

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

```
class Actor extends Component {

   constructor(props){ 
      this.handleCheck = this.handleCheck.bind(this);
   }

   state={
      voices : [
         {"Voice":"Indian English Female Voice 1"},
         {"Voice":"Indian English Female Voice 2"},
         {"Voice":"Indian English Male Voice 1"}
      ],
      checkedElement:""
   }

   handleCheck(){
      this.setState({checkedElement:event.target.value})
   }

   render(){
     return(
       {voices.map((item,index)=>{
            return(
                <label key={index} htmlFor = {item.Voice}>
                    {item.Voice}
                    <input
                       key = {index+1} 
                       value={item.Voice} 
                       type = "radio"  
                       onChange ={this.handleCheck}/>
                </label>
            )
        })}
     )
   }
}
```

This shows up as three options but once i check one of them, when i switch to the next option it does not uncheck the first one. It just stays checked and therefore not making it a unique selection.

Answer (score 0):

For the code above, you can add a property 'name' to input, just like

```html
<input 
  name={'item'} 
  key = {index+1} 
  value={item.Voice} 
  type = "radio"  
  onChange ={this.handleCheck}
 />.
```

you can also see the example from the [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/shy-paper-fepx0?file=/src/App.js).